# Template mobile application (Android & iOS ) design

Tags: android, ios, design-patterns, mobile, application-design

I need create many similar simple applications (Android and iOS) that consist of four tabs, each tab contains listview but it must be offline.

The difference between the apps will be only the content of the list and tabs names.
what is the best way to design this app ?

The first idea was putting configuration file and the app will load the info from there.

For sure i'm not the first dealing with this issue, maybe there is already solution or design for such problems ?

Maybe there is solution to load the content in compile time and not in run-time (as in my solution) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`You can create a class containing all the information you want and you can use the data from` that class instead of configuration file, and you can replace that class file for each individual app you create. This will be done at compile time rather run-time.

**For run time** best is to go with plist files for iOS and xml/properties file for android

**For Compile time** create a Class containing all data and replace it for each application version